# Permute using symmetric vs alternating groups

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

Why does this happen?

```
Permute[{0, 0, 0}, SymmetricGroup[3]]

(* {{0, 0, 0}} *)

Permute[{0, 0, 0}, AlternatingGroup[3]]

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified what you find surprising in these results and what results you were expecting instead.

Comment: Why not {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}} for S3

Comment: As you can see by trying `Permute[{a, a, b}, SymmetricGroup[3]]` and `Permute[{a, b, c}, SymmetricGroup[3]]`, `Permute` returns a list of non-identical results (essentially using something like `DeleteDuplicates` at the end).

Comment: @march But then, why does the `AlternatingGroup[3]` version have 3 identical results? I think this is probably a bug.

Comment: @CarlWoll. Yes, you're right: that's inconsistent behavior. Some basic playing around indicates that `SymmetricGroup` is the outlier here.